# Связь между предложениями при повествовании

Tags: синтаксис

При повествовании мы часто используем в начале предложения вводные слова/сочетания и наречия (например, «поэтому», «таким образом»), чтобы связать новое предложение с предыдущим. И меня всегда интересовал вопрос, а могут ли эти вводные слова/сочетания и наречия давать отсылку не к одному предшествующему предложению, а к нескольким предложениям вместе взятым, или синтаксические и смысловые связи могут устанавливаться лишь между соседними предложениями?

Comment: Но ведь сплошь и рядом такие вводные сочетания относятся не к одному предложению, а к нескольким, например, к целому абзацу. Достаточно открыть любой учебник для любого класса и убедиться.

Comment: А слова "таким образом" могут относиться не только к абзацу, но ко всему изложенному выше.

Comment: **Таким образом,** в данной работе показано, что... [«Вопросы вирусологии», 2004.01.05]

Comment: @М_Г Но ведь в вашем примере "таким образом" скорее относится с предыдущему предложению, по которому можно сделать вывод, что "в данной работе" что-то там показано.

Comment: @Niemand Можете найти какой-нибудь пример?

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко, Смотрите сами (http://elib.bsu.by/bitstream/123456789/95607/1/19-24.pdf) и убедитесь, что слова "таким образом" относятся ко всей статье в целом.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко, Пример давал не я, но неужели такое вас не убеждает: *[Пять или  десять абзацев текста] Таким образом, теорема доказана.*

Comment: @Niemand Прошу прощения — ошибочно указал ваше имя.

Comment: @М_Г К сожалению, не очень авторитетный пример. Сомневаюсь, что в данной работе "таким образом" употреблено верно. Грамота: "ТАКИМ ОБРАЗОМ, вводное сочетание. Употребляется для придания высказыванию значения вывода, следствия из того, что утверждалось ранее; то же, что «следовательно», «итак»". Там в предложении нет вывода или следствия из предыдущего текста — там просто итог, а "таким образом" употреблено "для красного словца".